# how to hide control caption

Tags: c#, asp.net

1. How to Hide TextBox Caption

   I want to be able to Hide the textboxes caption on my webform, I'm able to hide the textBoxes but not the Caption. can you please tell me what I'm missing.

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   if (cmdbox_TypePayment.SelectedIndex == 0)
   {
       txt_Carte.Visible = false;
       txt_CarteNum.Visible = false;
       txt_CarteDate.Visible = false;
       txt_CarteCCV.Visible = false;
   }
   }
   protected void cmdbox_TypePayment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   if (cmdbox_TypePayment.SelectedIndex == 0)
   {
       txt_Carte.Visible = false;
       txt_CarteNum.Visible = false;
       txt_CarteDate.Visible = false;
       txt_CarteCCV.Visible = false;
   }

    else if (cmdbox_TypePayment.SelectedIndex == 1)
   {
       txt_Carte.Visible = true;
       txt_CarteNum.Visible = true;
       txt_CarteDate.Visible = true;
       txt_CarteCCV.Visible = true;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Not following what you are trying to do.  Do you mean hide the text in the textbox rather than the textbox itself?

Comment: Are you referring to hiding the labels? If so then you need to set the visible property on the label to hide it. It sounds like your "text boxes" as you refer to them have a label and text box.

Comment: I want to Hide the labels of the textboxes

Comment: I may be thick, but didn't you say you can hide the textboxes already?  Just to quote, "I'm able to hide the textBoxes but not the Caption" :)

Comment: So the labels will have a name.. like `lbl_carte`.. just set visible to false on them.

Comment: Ah, I think @Graymatter got your meaning :)

Comment: Put the label and the textbox inside an `<asp:Panel>`.  Then set the panel visiblity to true/false.

Answer (score 0):

Set an **ID** for the label also and hide it in the same function..Suppose labelhas an ID **lblCaption**..

```
protected void cmdbox_TypePayment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmdbox_TypePayment.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
       lblCaption.Visible = false;
       txt_Carte.Visible = false;
       txt_CarteNum.Visible = false;
       txt_CarteDate.Visible = false;
       txt_CarteCCV.Visible = false;
    }

    else if (cmdbox_TypePayment.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
       lblCaption.Visible = true;
       txt_Carte.Visible = true;
       txt_CarteNum.Visible = true;
       txt_CarteDate.Visible = true;
       txt_CarteCCV.Visible = true;
    }
}
```